# Most efficient access to the rightmost/leftmost cousin node in a d3 tree

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js, tree, hierarchical-data

The D3 JavaScript visualization library has it's own implementation of [hierarchical structures](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy) and [trees](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#hierarchies-d3-hierarchy).

Nodes stores a reference to their parents (node.parent) and a reference to the children array (node.children), as well as their depth/height in the tree.

D3 offers also methods for [inorder/preorder/breath-first](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#node_each) traversal

Given that, what is the most efficient way to access the rightmost/leftmost cousin of a node ?

**For a tree:**

```
    root
   /    \
 a  b   c d
 /\ /\ /\ /\
e fg hi jk l
```

The *leftmost cousin* of **f** is **g** and the *rightmost cousin* of **c** is **b**

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to get the nodes to the left and to the right of a given node in a row, based on a simple feature of D3 trees: in that row, the nodes follow a **sequence** in the `descendants` array.

Let's see that using [this bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d8b2ce91e64a74f7d0295aed23635c2b/82b881eda34344d04ce68d47f35c2e8698a56af2). Unfortunately, I have to use a bl.ocks because the Stack Overflow snippet will freeze if I try to `console.log` a D3 selection (note: that bl.ocks is not mine, I just found it online).

So, in that bl.ocks, as you can see, the last row is:

> Son of A - Daughter of A - Son of B - Daughter of B - Son#2 of B

Let's get an array with those nodes (third row, depth = 2):

```
var row = nodes.descendants().filter(function(d) {
    return d.depth === 2
});
```

Now we have an array with all the nodes in the last row (5 elements).

Suppose we want to find who's at the left and right of `Son of B`. First, we get that specific node:

```
var sonOfB = row.filter(function(d) {
    return d.data.name === "Son of B"
});
```

And now comes the important part: if we know the index of that node in the array...

```
row.indexOf(sonOfB[0])
```

...we can get the nodes to its left and to its right:

```
var toTheLeft = row[row.indexOf(sonOfB[0]) - 1];
//to the left, subtract 1 -------------------^

var toTheRight = row[row.indexOf(sonOfB[0]) +1];
//to the right, add 1 -----------------------^
```

Look at the console in that bl.ocks. You'll see this:

```
console.log("To the left: " + toTheLeft.data.name)
    //returns "To the left: Daughter of A"
console.log("To the Right: " + toTheRight.data.name)
    //returns "To the Right: Daughter of B"
```

PS: That's *one way* to access the left/right nodes. I'll avoid saying anything about *"the most efficient"* way because it seems pretty opinion-based. Maybe *"the most idiomatic"* way is a better question, but even so, it's questionable.

Comment: Hello Gerardo, that is a very clever way to o this, thank you for your answer. By *most efficient* I meant most *computationally efficient*. I know, that *O(n+log(n))* is probably the hard-limit here, but creating the *descendants array* + filtering for nodes with certain depth will traverse the tree two times I guess. I am curious if someone comes with anther approach.

Comment: Actually, just once: you probably already have a `descendants` array somewhere in your code.